# C# generic types in interfaces as placeholders?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, factory

I'm trying to do the following -

```
interface I1<PlaceHolder> {}
class C1 : I1<ActualClass> {
public Method() { ActualClass class = new ActualClass();}}
```

It works but then C# doesn't allow the below -

```
interface IFactory<PlaceHolder> { I1 Create<PlaceHolder>(); } 
class ConcreteFactory<ActualClass> {
public I1 Create<ActualClass>() { return new C1(); //Won't work }
}
```

If I try to add the generic types to C1 then the below won't work

```
class C1<ActualClass> : I1<ActualClass> {
    public Method() { ActualClass class = new ActualClass(); //Won't work}
}
```

I wonder if C# allows some implementation of the above via its language features?

**EDIT 1**:

Please see below a more real world example of the above (ValidationResultA and ValidationResultB are concrete classes that do not share a base class and can potentially have different properties) -

```
interface IProcessor<Validator, ValidationResult> { 
ValidationResult ValidateProcess(); 
void RunProcess();
}

class ProcessorA : IProcessor<ValidatorA, ValidationResultA> {
ValidationResultA ValidateProcess() {
    ValidatorA validator = new ValidatorA();
    ValidationResultA result = validator.DoSomething();
    result.IsAAA = true;
    return result;
}

class ProcessorB : IProcessor<ValidatorB, ValidationResultB> {
ValidationResultB ValidateProcess() {
    ValidationResultB validator = new ValidationResultB();
    ValidationResultB result = validator.DoSomething();
    result.IsBBB = true;
    return validator;
}
```

And then we can create ProcessorFactory that returns IProcess.

We achieved 2 things with this -
1. We were able to overload ValidateProcess' on return type.
2. We were able to create implementations of IProcessor and plug varied Validators and ValidationResults in it.

Comment: Your code doesn't even make sense.  You created a generic `I1<T>` then your code uses a non generic version of `I1`??

Comment: Yes, the idea being that interface being able to create a "contract" without knowing the PlaceHolder type. The subclasses are free to either substitute a placeholder with a concrete type or continue with the placeholder. The real problem that I'm trying to solve is to be able to create a hierarchy without creating a contract. For example, the placeholder can be an "Config" and each subclass can use it's own type of Config (FileConfig, DBConfig etc) without the specific Configs subclassing from the same base because they may not have same methods/properties etc.

Comment: Don't use interfaces as markers for capabilities. Use interfaces as they were intended to be used: as abstractions of contracts. It sounds like you are trying to solve a problem in the type system that the type system was not intended to solve.

Comment: @EricLippert Understood.

Comment: To add to my previous comment about the "why", this type of setup also allows me to achieve a kind of polymorphism on a method's return type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create new instances of a generic type you need

```
class MyClass<T> where T : new()
```

so :-

```
interface I1<PlaceHolder>
{        
}
class C1<ActualClass> : I1<ActualClass> where ActualClass: new()
{
    public void Method()
    {
        ActualClass c = new ActualClass();
    }
}

interface IFactory<PlaceHolder> where PlaceHolder : new()
{
    I1<PlaceHolder> Create<PlaceHolder>(); 

}
class ConcreteFactory<ActualClass>  where ActualClass : new()
{
    public I1<ActualClass> Create()
    {
        return new C1<ActualClass>(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but now it seems the properties of ActualClass have become inaccessible - `public void Method() { ActualClass c = new ActualClass(); c.Prop1 = 1; //Prop1 is not there anymore }

Comment: no, it won't be available, It's Generic, it doesn't know of any properties that  class has.  actualClass could be most any type !

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your question what you're trying to achieve, but it seems like you need generic constraints to solve this. There are a few different constraints you can use:

- T must have an empty constructor: `public class MyClass<T> where T : new()`
- T inherits/implements base class/interface: `public class MyClass<T> where T : SomeOtherClass`
- T is a class: `public class MyClass<T> where T : class`
- T is a struct: `public class MyClass where T : struct

You can combine the above by separating them with comma's, keeping in mind that the `new()` constraint always needs to go last, eg:

```
// T must implement IDisposable, inherit from SomeClass and have a public 
// parameterless constructor
public class MyClass<T> where T : IDisposable, SomeClass, new()
```

With that in mind, what *"I think"* you're after is the following solution:

```
interface I1<T>
{
}

class ActualClass
{
}

class C1 : I1<ActualClass>
{
    public C1()
    {
        ActualClass class1 = new ActualClass();
    }
}

interface IFactory
{
    I1<T> Create<T>();
}

class ConcreteFactory
{
    public I1<T> Create<T>() where T : I1<T>, new()
    {
        return new T(); 
    }
}
```

Why you would want to do that, is beyond me, but the above implementation works. You can play around with the generic constraints to see if you solve your problem.

In the other case, it's probably better to modify your question and give us a real example.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question with a real world example.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles:

```
interface I1<PlaceHolder> where PlaceHolder : new()  { }

class ActualClass {}

class C1 : I1<ActualClass> 
{
   public void Method() { ActualClass @class = new ActualClass();}
}

interface IFactory<PlaceHolder> where PlaceHolder : new() 
{
   I1<PlaceHolder> Create();  
} 

class ConcreteFactory : IFactory<ActualClass>
{
   public I1<ActualClass> Create() { return new C1(); }
}
```